# How to use dataset along with model in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ado.net, .net-6.0

```
@using System.Data;    
@model DataSet;     
@using WebApplication4.Models;
```

I am using a dataset to retrieve table data, but in addition to that I also want to use another model, i.e., `@model MyViewModel` like this:

```
@using System.Data;
@model DataSet
@using WebApplication4.Models;
@model MyViewModel;
```

I get an error

> Model directive occur only one per document

How to put these dataset inside the mode in order to import only `MyViewModel` model which consists of dataset data inside it?

Answer (score 2):

you will have to create a special view model class

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public DataSet MyDataSet { get; set; }
    public MyAnotherModel MyAnotherModel { get; set; }
}
```

GET view action

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetMyView()
{
    var  dataSet = ... your code
    myAnotherModel = ... your coe

    var model= new ViewModel
    {
     MyDataSet =dataSet;
     MyAnotherModel =myAnotherModel
      }

return View (model);
}
```

GET view

```
@model ViewModel
....
```

POST view action

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostMyView(ViewModel model)
{
    .... your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A view can have only one model.  But that model can be anything you like.

For example, if you want your model to have a `DataSet` property:

```
public DataSet MyDataSet { get; set; }
```

Or perhaps you want to create a custom view model composed of both a `DataSet` and your model:

```
public class MyCompositeViewModel
{
    public DataSet MyDataSet { get; set; }
    public MyViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

You can construct any object you like to pass from the controller to the view.  So while you can use only a single model instance, that model instance can be composed of whatever you need for the view.

Comment: How to put it in the view?

Comment: @aayush: Can you clarify what you mean?  Presumably you already know how to use the `@model` directive in your view, since you demonstrate that in the question.  And passing the model to the view, as well as using it within the view, is fundamental to ASP.NET MVC...

Comment: @aayush: just use `@model MyCompositeViewModel;` in your view - now you have a "composite" view model which contains both the `MyDataSet` as well as the `ViewModel` as members, in your view